# Asking question which has subjective answer?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask technical question about my website but it has rather a subjective answer, like there is answer but many people might have different opinion on it.
It's a question like: "What is the problem in the case of doing X and Y and same time? And what problems may it cause?"

So can it be asked on Stackoverflow or should I look for different community for that question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those questions are typically off-topic on SO; only questions that have universal answers can be of benefit to everyone.

However, your question about potential problems in a given solution isn't necessarily a bad one. It might be something you propose has some well-known issues.

Comment: Well imagine a question like: Many people say it's bad to use mobile phone on petrol station. What problems could it cause?

So question like that, it might outline some potential problems. 

But mine is tech related of course.

Comment: @arleitiss Sounds too broad. Besides the immediate "it could cause an explosion" that would come to the mind of many, there could be a whole slew of other problems people could bring up: "you could be mugged", "you could not be paying enough attention to realize that a skimmer has been installed on the pump", "the metal could cause a drop in signal", etc.

Comment: @Louis I guess I will refrain from posting question then. Thanks.