# How can I ask a coding style question on SO?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445012/clean-coding-resulting-in-many-utility-classes) on SO which lead to a pretty unpleasant exchange and a lot of heat. The issue was that I wanted to say "if you follow a certain coding style then how do you avoid problem X". The comments were almost all from people who didn't understand the style or thought it was stupid. Consequently I did not get any information from people who do follow the style and had a genuine suggestion for me.

My question is, how could I have phrased it better to avoid this outcome? Should I have started by suggesting answers only from people who had read the book I was referring to? Should I have specifically said that I did not want comments on the style itself?

Comment: You cannot try to control  or limit who gets to answer or comments on your posts here. This is a public site, where anyone who can answer or comment is free to do so. If you want to limit those who answer or comment, you've chosen the wrong site. (If you try to provide those instructions, either someone will edit to remove them or you'll collect a lot of downvotes for doing so.) After reading your question, it's pretty broad in scope, and might be better asked at either [programmers.se] or [codereview.se] rather than [so].

Comment: @KenWhite I guess I wasn't suggesting stopping anyone answering - just proposing who might be interested in answering. But I take your point about it being broad. It's a shame because it's a genuine question that generates a lot of discussion in my company. I guess I'll have to look elsewhere for answers.

Comment: @sprinter It can also generate a ton of flame wars; thats why opinion questions such as that are not allowed here.

Comment: @Isaiah I was actually trying not to ask opinion - I was trying to ask 'how do I follow this coding style correctly'. But I suspect I worded it badly - or it's just not the sort of question that can can be answered in this type of forum.

Comment: @Isaiah after the flaming started I wanted to delete the question as I realised I wasn't going to get any useful information. But I was warned that it could effect my reputation so I voted to close it instead. What should I have done? Let me know if I should raise this as a separate question.

Comment: Voting to close as `primarily opinion based` or `too broad` would be the logical choice.

Comment: @Isaiah Yes that's what I did. Unfortunately there weren't enough votes to close so the flaming continued!

Comment: Well closing doesb't disable commenting, so flag for moderator attention and explain your problem there

Comment: see also: [Asking question which has subjective answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282914/asking-question-which-has-subjective-answer)

Comment: @gnat thanks for directing me to that first question - that was exactly what I was getting at: I am a very experienced developer (20+ years across 7 companies and at least 20 languages) wanting to ask advice from other very experienced developers. So many questions are from people that have just started coding that the assumption is that the answer you are looking for is easy. Sadly from reading similar questions to mine triggering pointless responses I've concluded that SO is best  suited to specific technical questions with specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel that such questions would be considered too broad or primarily opinion based as coding style is 95% subjective and 5% objective. In other words, such questions will cause strife and if it gets out of hand, flame wars just because not everyone agrees with a particular style.

If you can find a way to word it in an objective manner (I bet its possible), then it may still be considered too broad.

It may be possible to ask it on another site, but such a question would be nearly impossible to ask on SO without being considered too broad or primarily opinion based.